# Finding lines missing a bracket

Tags: bash

I have a file with some brackets:

```
{ This is } some text. { This } is some other text.
```

The brackets always come in pairs, and are occasionally nested, but never appear across multiple lines, such as here:

```
{ This is } some text. { This
is some other text. }
```

I want to search for some errors, in which a bracket is missing. How can I locate any lines that are missing a matching bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '(length(gensub("[^{]","","g"))-length(gensub("[^}]","","g"))) != 0 { print NR, $0}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/{[^{}]*}//g' input.txt | grep -n '[{}]'
```

Comment: Does this cater for the '`occasionally nested`' parens?

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `perl`:

```
perl -lne '
  BEGIN { 
    our $bo, $bc;
  } 
  m/(?: \{ (?{ ++$bo }) | \} (?{ ++$bc }) | . ) */x;  
  if ( $bo != $bc ) { 
    printf qq[%s (Line %d): %s\n], qq[Missing bracket], $., $_; 
  } 
  $bo = $bc = 0
' infile
```

Variable `$bo` means an opening bracket and `$bc` means a closing bracket. The regexp increments the variables when one of them found and compares its values after that. If different, print line.

With this input file (**infile**):

```
{ This is } some text. { This } is some other text.
{ This is } some text. { This
is some other text. }
```

Result:

```
Missing bracket (Line 2): { This is } some text. { This
Missing bracket (Line 3): is some other text. }
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -pane '$rr = qr/{[^{}]*(??{$rr})*[^{}]*}/; s/$rr//g;' input.txt | grep -n '[{}]'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/{[^{}]*}//g;ta;/[{}]/=;d' file
```

This prints out the line number of unbalanced lines. If you want the line too:

```
sed 'h;:a;s/{[^{}]*}//g;ta;/[{}]/!d;=;g' | sed 'N;s/\n/:/'
```